# How do you spot the left side pedal on egg beater pedals?

Tags: maintenance, pedals

I've just got a new set of crank brothers egg beater pedals and I can't tell which pedal is for the left side, and which is for the right just from looking at them.  Is there an obvious way to tell without simply trying to screw them in?

Update: There isn't an obvious L and R that I (or another pair of eyes) could see.  The only text I could see was really fine print that mentioned the torque to put the pedals in.  I couldn't see anything in the instructions that appeared to say which one was which either.

Comment: Usually if you look closely at the spindles there's an "R" stamped on one and an "L" stamped on the other.  But simply checking the thread works too.  Grip the thread between the fingers of your left hand and "unscrew" with the right -- see which way the threads seem to be moving.

Comment: @DanielRHicks That's a nice idea.  I'm too used to seeing an L and an R so I didn't have any neat tricks for determining which is which.  Well until all the answers came into this question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is from the Crank Brothers pdf available on their site or in the package:

> Eggbeater pedals have either a 6mm Hex, an 8mm Hex, and/or 15mm wrench flats.  Note that ***the right pedal has a 
>   standard right-handed thread and the left pedal has a left-handed thread***.  For identification, left pedal has a small 
>   “L” on the spindle or a small groove around the spindle flange.  The right pedal has a small "R" stamped in the 
>   spindle or no special markings.

In my case there was no "L" on the spindle, but there is a small groove around  the left spindle flange.

The link: http://www.crankbrothers.com/support/product_documentation/instructions_eggbeater.pdf

Comment: Mine have the groove too, just as they say.  I double checked my instructions though and I definitely can't find any reference to it in them.  I guess they got lost in translation ;)  (Actually they are in English but it's a big sheet with multiple languages so I guess that might not be so far from the truth).  Anyway that answers the question thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If they aren't marked with a big L and R, you could just inspect the threads. Whichever one has  reverse threads is the left pedal. You can tell reverse threads because they are oriented toward the north-west rather than the north-east.

Comment: +1 I may mark this one as the answer if there isn't a specific way to spot the egg beaters orientation any other way.  I'll leave it open for a bit to see if there are any owners of that model about who can say.

Answer (score 5):

Looking from the top down standing over the bike and holding the pedals in the way they should go into the cranks, the threads of the left pedal angle like this (towards the left side crank): /////

The threads of the right pedal angle like this (towards the right side crank): \\\\\

Both pedals thread in to the front and out to the rear.

Answer (score 2):

When you remove your old pedals look at the first one you remove.Compare the threads with one of your new ones,you should be able to notice that the threads are not perpendicular to the shaft but have a slight angle.The angles should appear to be different between the two new pedals,one leaning left one leaning right.If you have removed only one of your old pedals you can match the threads and install the new one.Then remove the second and install the other new one.If they are marked just remember left is referenced to you sitting on the bike.

Answer (score 2):

On the pedal spindle, right after the threads, there is a 1/4" wide smooth metal bushing. One will be totally smooth, the other will have a thin groove in the center.

The left pedal will have the groove.

Answer (score 2):

"Right after the threads??"
Maybe you're saying the solution is like this:  Hold one pedal with the platform part in your left hand with the spindle (the black part with the threads thst screws into the crank arm) pointing to the right.  Immediately to the left of the threads, check the largest diameter part of the spindle (the black part that screws in).  Only one of the two pedals will have a groove cut into it.

Comment: Continued:  The pedal with the groove is the LEFT one.

Comment: THANK YOU <3 Case any other non native is trying to decode what a "small groove" actually means, where the screw ends and the pedal begins there is a "cut" on the whole circumference of the piece.